# While evaluating my ViT model using model.evaluate(x_test, y_test) in keras, it gives me more than 100% accuracy. Why?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

from sklearn.utils import class_weight
no_classes = 2

def run_experiment(model):

```
optimizer = tfa.optimizers.AdamW(
    learning_rate=learning_rate, weight_decay=weight_decay
)

model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[
        keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(name="accuracy"),
        keras.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(5, name="top-5-accuracy"),
    ],
)
!mkdir "/content/CV_Checkpoints"
checkpoint_filepath = "/content/CV_Checkpoints/"
checkpoint_callback = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    checkpoint_filepath,
    monitor="val_accuracy",
    save_best_only=True,
    save_weights_only=True,
)

history = model.fit(
    x=x_train,
    y=y_train,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=num_epochs,
    validation_split=0.1,
    callbacks=[checkpoint_callback],
)

model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
_, accuracy, top_5_accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(f"Test accuracy: {round(accuracy * 100, 2)}%")
print(f"Test top 5 accuracy: {round(top_5_accuracy * 100, 2)}%")
predicted_label.append(np.argmax(model.predict(x_test),axis=-1))

return history
```

vit_classifier = create_vit_classifier()
history = run_experiment(vit_classifier)

Output:
Epoch 1/15
1/1 [==============================] - 12s 12s/step - loss: 1.2682 - accuracy: 3.8050 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0278 - val_accuracy: 1.1921e-07 - val_top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 2/15
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 1s/step - loss: 3.5516 - accuracy: 6.5027 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 37.0684 - val_accuracy: 16.1181 - val_top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 3/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 190ms/step - loss: 11.7986 - accuracy: 4.5956 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 10.2448 - val_accuracy: 16.1181 - val_top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 4/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 177ms/step - loss: 4.1671 - accuracy: 4.6267 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.9128 - val_accuracy: 1.8679 - val_top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 5/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 170ms/step - loss: 8.1745 - accuracy: 10.4437 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 8.3098 - val_accuracy: 10.8216 - val_top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 6/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 170ms/step - loss: 3.4625 - accuracy: 3.8120 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 5.8123 - val_accuracy: 12.3951 - val_top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 7/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 179ms/step - loss: 3.3535 - accuracy: 4.2599 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.6153 - val_accuracy: 5.3999 - val_top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 8/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 164ms/step - loss: 1.6320 - accuracy: 2.2927 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0629 - val_accuracy: 0.0770 - val_top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 9/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 165ms/step - loss: 1.8593 - accuracy: 3.0573 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 4.1515 - val_accuracy: 12.6133 - val_top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 10/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 224ms/step - loss: 2.0062 - accuracy: 3.6780 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 2.5899 - val_accuracy: 9.3397 - val_top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 11/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 250ms/step - loss: 1.9134 - accuracy: 3.9371 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.2281 - val_accuracy: 1.8226 - val_top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 12/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 239ms/step - loss: 1.5485 - accuracy: 2.5761 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.0980 - val_accuracy: 0.0584 - val_top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 13/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 172ms/step - loss: 1.4785 - accuracy: 2.1410 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.4698 - val_accuracy: 1.0202 - val_top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 14/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 167ms/step - loss: 1.3027 - accuracy: 3.4242 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 2.3393 - val_accuracy: 7.6722 - val_top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 15/15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 165ms/step - loss: 1.5553 - accuracy: 3.1357 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.6237 - val_accuracy: 0.5839 - val_top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 24ms/step - loss: 13.3386 - accuracy: 5.7951 - top-5-accuracy: 1.0000
Test accuracy: 579.51%
Test top 5 accuracy: 100.0%

Comment: No, what you are interpreting as accuracy is actually loss, evaluate returns loss and metrics.

Comment: For example this makes no sense: SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(name="accuracy"), you have a loss named accuracy.

Comment: after you name your loss and metrics properly, you should use `model.evaluate(..., return_dict=True)` to return a dictionary of the results. that will make it easier to know what the values mean.

Comment: Heartiest thanks Dr. Snoopy and Jakub for your valuable suggestions. Based on your suggestions, I have finally figured out that the problem was the metrics name. :( I just replaced the "SparseCategoricalCrossentropy" with "SparseCategoricalAccuracy", it's now giving me loss, accuracy and top-5 accuracy properly. There was a very small mistake that did not catch my eye.--@Dr.Snoopy @jakub

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).